# Accessing static files in Golang

Tags: html, css, go, static-files, fileserver

I am having trouble linking to an external CSS file in one of my served pages in a Go Server.

This is my project structure, with some comments. My `$GOPATH`, is the top-level directory. Note that there is a "main" executable that was built via using the ***"$go build main"*** command from this top-level directory. It essentially compiled the files in the `src/main` directory. I then run the program directly through this executable ("$.\main").

```
.
├── bin
├── main <-- Executable, not directory (built via "go build main")
├── pkg
│   └── darwin_amd64
├── src
│   ├── github.com
│   └── main <---- My Go files are here!
├── style
│   └── style.css
└── templates
    └── developers.html
```

I am trying to use the `style.css` file as an externally linked style file in the developers.html template, that is eventually parsed and merged by Go. The files are listed below, in simplified versions.

## developers.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

## server.go

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    styleHandler := http.FileServer(http.Dir("style"))
    http.Handle("/style/", http.StripPrefix("/style/", styleHandler))

    // router handles other non-static pages, 
    // and is defined in another .go source file. These are working.
    router := MainRouter()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

I'm sure the problem is how I'm treating the relative paths, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hey @RichC, thanks for the response. Nada. Web console gives me the following: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: What is the URL you are trying to hit? What is giving you a 404?

Comment: @d1str0 : localhost:8080/style/style.css

Comment: try adding a "/" to your link, before the word "style":  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style/style.css">... that may also be necessary in your http.FileServer.

Comment: @Snowman : Didn't help.

Comment: @Snowman : I am using gorilla/mux as my router, instead of Golang's normal one. Could that be affecting something?

Comment: hmmm.. because I was able to break one of my servers by removing the leading / in the http.Dir. Do you the source and resources on GitHub? I have about an hour that I could try and build and break it if you want.

Comment: well since using the default should take about 10 seconds to test why not try and see if you get a different results/?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104595/discussion-between-snowman-and-jhc).

Comment: @jhc I think it's http.Dir("style"). http.Dir() wants absolute path to my mind.

Comment: @Uvelichitel it's already at "style", what change are you suggesting?

Comment: @jhc http.Dir("/absolut/rooted/path/to/style") because of http.Dir.Open() doesn't know about your current_working_directory and can't assume relative path I'm afraid.

Comment: @Uvelichitel just tried. Didn't help.